# Ways to setup a Ninject singleton

Tags: c#, singleton, ninject

I have a class (`MyFacade`) that I injected parameter(s) with `Ninject`:

```
class MyFacade
{
    IDemoInterface demo;

    public MyFacade(IDemoInterface demo)
    {
        this.demo = demo;
    }

    public void MyMethod()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(demo.GetInfo());
    }
}
```

Of course, I have to setup the `Ninject` to inject the appropiate implementation of my parameter (`IDemoInterface`)

I know, I can instantiate `MyFacade` object by doing `kernel.Get<MyFacade>();` without setting anything else. Currently my facade doesn't have an interface (because it is my only implementation, maybe I will add its interface for standard proposes)

if I want to make this facade singlenton, I know two ways: create a empty constructor and pass a parameter by doing this `kernel.Get<IDemoInterface>();` or by setup Ninject like: `kernel.Bind<MyFacade>().To<MyFacade>().InSingletonScope();`

The second one look a better approach, but do you know any other way to setup it in a singleton way?

Comment: I also can do `kernel.Bind<MyFacade>().ToSelf().InSingletonScope();`

Comment: Actually your first option shouldn't be an option, since the singleton pattern doesn't allow having public constructors.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

When setting up your bindings, you need to bind your dependencies. It is always better to setup your dependencies in your bindings, as opposed to doing a `kernel.Get<T>()` in a constructor. You are using IOC, so leverage the framework you are using to do the injection for you.

In your second example binding, what you are missing is binding in your `IDemoInterface`. Your bindings should look like this:

```cs
//bind the dependency to the implementation.
kernel.Bind<IDemoInterface>().To<DemoInterface>();
//since you bound your dependency, ninject should now have 
// all the dependencies required to instantiate your `MyFacade` object.
kernel.Bind<MyFacade>().To<MyFacade>().InSingletonScope();
```

Comment: That is what I though. One more thing, in order to avoid direct instantiate, normally singleton use private ctor... is that possible with Ninject?

Comment: It's not possible, as far a I'm aware, with Ninject. Ninject requires a public constructor in order to know how to instantiate an instance of your object for injection.

Comment: See this discussion about default public constructors and mechanisms for getting around them: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21665839/ninject-injecting-singleton

Comment: @Jaider I know this is an old question, but a way to use Ninject like this and still avoid a publicly available constructor is to have the class implement a public interface but be internal itself. The project responsible for the Ninject bindings then needs to be given access to the relevant internals.

Answer (score 6):

If you do not want the container to manage the lifecycle of your singleton by using `InSingletonScope()`, but still wants it to get injected, I can think of 2 ways to go about it. Choose which one suits better to your needs. Consider the following `ISingleton` (name your interface) implementation:

```
public class ConcreteSingleton : ISingleton
{
    private static readonly Lazy<ConcreteSingleton> _instance = new Lazy<ConcreteSingleton>(() => new ConcreteSingleton());

    private ConcreteSingleton() { }

    public static ConcreteSingleton Instance
    {
        get
        {
            return _instance.Value;
        }
    }
}
```

1. **Alter the singleton class to have a** `GetInstance(...)` **method**

   In this method (my preferred approach), you won't be calling `kernel.Inject(instance)` each time, only for the first time the singleton is initialized. Adding the following method to your `ConcreteSingleton` class:

   ```
   public static ConcreteSingleton GetInstance(IKernel kernelForInjection)
   {
       if (_instance.IsValueCreated == false)
       {
           kernelForInjection.Inject(_instance.Value);
       }

       return _instance.Value;
   }
   ```

   And using this binding:

   ```
   kernel.Bind<ISingleton>().ToMethod(c => ConcreteSingleton.GetInstance(c.Kernel));
   ```

   Will achieve the desired behavior of not having a public constructor but enabling your facade to be efficiently injected.
2. **Perform injection each time the** `ISingleton` **instance is requested**

   If by any reason you are not allowed to modify your `ConcreteSingleton`: This approach will wrap the singleton creation in a provider to efficiently inject the instance only for the first time it is created. It is important to note that the provider itself must be registered as a singleton.

   ```
   internal class ConcreteSingletonProvider : Provider<ISingleton>
   {
       public IKernel Kernel { get; set; }

       //Just a wrapper
       private readonly Lazy<ISingleton> _lazy = new Lazy<ISingleton>(() => ConcreteSingleton.Instance);

       public ConcreteSingletonProvider(IKernel kernel)
       {
           Kernel = kernel;
       }

       protected override ISingleton CreateInstance(IContext context)
       {
           if (_lazy.IsValueCreated == false)
           {
               Kernel.Inject(ConcreteSingleton.Instance);
           }
           return _lazy.Value;
       }
   }
   ```

   And your bindings should be like this:

   ```
   kernel.Bind<ISingleton>().ToProvider<ConcreteSingletonProvider>();
   kernel.Bind<ConcreteSingletonProvider>().ToSelf().InSingletonScope();
   ```

   This [gist](https://gist.github.com/cvbarros/8940440) has a complete working sample for the above approach.

Hope that helps!